# Загрузка измененных файлов с github на сервер

Tags: git, github

Возникла такая проблема, создал репозиторий на github и загрузил туда свои файлы, затем файлы из репозитория загрузил на сервер. Затем внес изменения в коде на локальной машине, закоммитил эти изменения и залил их на github, и теперь у меня вопрос, по какой команде я могу загрузить эти измененные файлы на сервер?
Или же нужно заново клонировать репозиторий на сервер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете загрузить файлы из репозитория на сервер следующей командой (при условии, что на сервере и локально работаете в одной и той же ветке)

```
git pull
```

Команда выполняется на сервере.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15745424/5951529 — пробовали? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, git stash используется для временного хранения изменений, которые пока рано коммитить. Однако, их нужно сохранить, например, для ребейза или переключения на другую ветку. Тут вроде совсем другая задача, а, автор вопроса про ветки не упоминает.

Comment: Топикстартер здесь оставил сообщение, а затем удалил. Ему отвечал. Спасибо.

Comment: Понятно, извиняюсь за невольный наезд :).

Comment: я извиняюсь, что забыл указать адресата сообщения через `@`. Спасибо.